# Is there a better way to split of objects by one of its attributes?

Tags: python, list, google-app-engine, sorting, python-2.7

I'm currently working on an AppEngine app and have a list of objects from the datastore that I want to split into groups based on one of their attributes. I have a solution to this, but I wanted to check if anyone knows of a better way to do this.

This is the code that I have at the moment:

```
for report in reports:
  if report.status == 'new':
    new_reports.append(report)
  elif report.status == 'read':
    read_reports.append(report)
  elif report.status == 'accepted':
    accepted_reports.append(report)
  elif report.status == 'deined':
    denied_reports.append(report)
  elif report.status == 'resubmitted':
    resubmitted_reports.append(report)
```

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary would be nice instead of all the local variables:

```
reports_by_status = {'new': [],
     'read': [],
     'accepted': [],
     'deined': [],    # denied?
     'resubmitted': []}

for report in reports:
    d[report.status].append(report)
```

But you made a typo! It might be nice to prevent that by using whatever data is in the `status` variable to assign a category:

```
reports_by_status = {}
for report in reports:
    if report.status not in reports_by_status:
        reports_by_status[status] = []
    reports_by_status[status].append(report)
```

This is a common pattern, so we have a few ways to make it nicer:

```
reports_by_status = {}
for report in reports:
    reports_by_status.set_default(report.status, []).append(report)
```

but nicer is a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
by_status = defaultdict(list)
for report in reports:
    by_status[report].append(report)
```

`itertools.groupby` is nice, it encapsulates the categorization action:

```
from itertools import groupby
by_status = {}
for category, group in groupby(reports, lambda x: x.status):
    by_status[category] = list(group)
```

but now our loop is looking `map()`-ish, so let's use a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
dict([(k:list(v)) for k, v in groupby(reports, lambda x: x.status)])
```

and then remember that we're in Python 2.7, so we have dictionary comprehensions too:

```
from itertools import groupby
{k:list(v) for k, v in groupby(reports, lambda x: x.status)}
```

or my favorite so far,

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter
{k:list(v) for k, v in groupby(reports, attrgetter('status'))}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can have a dict from status to function like this:

```
d= {"new":new_reports.append,
    "read":read_reports.append,
    "accepted":accepted_reports.append,
    "deined":denied_reports.append,
    "resubmitted":resubmitted_reports.append
}

for report in reports:
     d[report.status](report)
```

Comment: I kind of like this - a nice reminder of how method objects get bound too.

Comment: @Thomas i love this because i come from java ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about a dictionary:

```
dct = {"new":new_reports, "read":read_reports, "accepted":accepted_reports, "denied":denied_reports, "resubmitted":resubmitted_reports}
for report in reports:
    dct[report.status].append(report)
```

or, if there is a chance that a `report.status` is not in the dictionary, you can add a try/except block:

```
dct = {"new":new_reports, "read":read_reports,"accepted":accepted_reports, "denied":denied_reports, "resubmitted":resubmitted_reports}
for report in reports:
    try:
        dct[report.status].append(report)
    except KeyError:
        continue
```